# SOQL Query for updating related records

Tags: soql, data-loader, relationships, dataloader.io

I have two Objects: Opportunity and Bid(custom Object). A bid is having a lookup field to opportunity i.e. an opp. can have multiple bids.

I need to update the comment field of Bid records, but the condition is I need to update only the latest created bid record of an open Opportunity. For example, if an open opp. is having 4 bid records and 4th bid is the latest created bid then I need to update only 4th bid record.

I need to achieve this scenario for multiple open opp. using data loader. I am not sure how to write SOQL for this and is this scenario possible to achieve using data.

Answer (score 0):

welcome!

In that case, you could use a nested query ordering the child records by `CreatedDate`, descending. Something like:

```
SELECT Id, 
      (SELECT Id, Comment__c 
         FROM Your_Child_Record_Relationship__r 
         ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
         LIMIT 1) 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE (your Opportunity filters here)
```

You can find the name of your `Child Relationship Name` on the Opportunity field of your custom object (Bid).

By exporting the child records, you will probably be able to use a data loader to update the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am still struggling with this. Is this possible to convert this query to Bid object instead of Opportunity?

Comment: @NikhilSinghal not in a single query due to the data configuration (Opportunity is the "parent" object, Bid is the child). You could grab a list of the Opportunity`Id`s first and then use this list to filter down your Bid records query, using Apex or exporting the data in different steps to something like a spreadsheet.